# Azure Network Security Group inbound filter for Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

In my Azure VNET I have an AppService that's using Azure Search. I'm trying to use NSG Inbound Rules to restrict access to the Azure Service using IPs. Unfortunately, in the NSG configuration blade, I can specify the destination only using the IP or VNET. How can I isolate the traffic to Azure Search?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Azure NSG doesn't support specify Azure Search as the source/destination.**

For now, Azure NSG only support IP Address and Service Tag as the source. And the Service Tag contains Intranet, a specfic Azure VNet, Azure Loadbalancer,Azure Traffic Manager , Storage and SQL.

For the destination, as you seen, it only support IP address and VNet. This is because Azure NSG can only be associated to VMs, NICs, VNets and subnets. These resources are all IaaS services.

However, Auzre Search is a PaaS service, it doesn't have VNet in portal which can be associated to NSG. So, it cannot used as the destination of NSG.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks Wayne. Does this mean that there is no way to make any Azure PaaS service undiscoverable? I'm just looking for options to shield my Azure Search from the public view.

Answer (score 0):

There are options now, 4 years later. See "Security Overview for Azure Cognitive Search".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-overview

It should be relatively safe (but not undetectable) on the *.windows.net space, there would be WAF mitigations. People use shared secrets for SSH after all. It is a matter of looking after those keys as well.

No cheap solution, but you are presumably paying by the hour for the search service in any case. Firewalls, private endpoints, key vaults, it all adds up.